# Unity Editor wont connect to firebase auth

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm here to make a game with anonymous login with firebase auth, and a database with firebase real-time database, everything works smoothly except for firebase auth. The problem is I don't know why? the unity won't connect to firebase auth.

### Installation

I already install the package like always database and auth [image]

also for the firebase is like this
[image]

### Script

here my login script :

```cs
//Firebase variables
    [Header("Firebase")]
    public DependencyStatus dependencyStatus;
    public FirebaseAuth auth;
    public FirebaseUser User;
    public DatabaseReference DBreference;
    public static FirebaseManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            instance = this;
        }

        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                InitializeFirebase();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(
                    "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependency status);
            }
        });
    }

    public void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
        AuthStateChanged(this, null);

    }

    void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //This checks if the user (your local user) is the same as the one from the auth
        if (auth.CurrentUser != User)
        {
            bool signedIn = User != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
            User = auth.CurrentUser;
            if (signedIn)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed in " + User.UserId + " " + User.DisplayName);
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine(SignAnonymously());
            }
        }
    }

    //it does not directly log the user out but invalidates the auth
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
        auth = null;
    }

    public IEnumerator SignAnonymously()
    {
        var loginTask = auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => loginTask.IsCompleted);

        if (loginTask.Exception != null)
        {
            //If there are errors handle them
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {loginTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            User = loginTask.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", User.DisplayName, User.UserId);
        }
    }
```

### What I've tried

- Check the google-service.json ( already same or updated )
- already implement this https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/firebase-compatibility-with-unity-20201.html due to a compatibility issue.
- already changed `continuewith` to `ContinueWithOnMainThread(task..`

note: I'm using unity ver 2020.3.1f1 LTS

am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Lotan thanks, but the real-time database works correctly, the problem is on the auth why it won't connect to the firebase auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your Coroutine method `SignAnonymously` with this async method:

```
public async void SignAnonymously()
{
   await auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
      if (task.IsCanceled) {
        Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync was canceled.");
        return;
      }
      if (task.IsFaulted) {
        Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
        return;
      }

      Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
      Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
          newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
    });
}
```

I think that the problem could be the lacking of `ContinueWith`at the end of your `SignInAnonymouslyAsync`, maybe you can use it on your Coroutine but I've never done it that way, tell me if it works ^^